# Synchronizend Socket messages in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm new to `Sockets` and I've written a **TCP** client following tutorials, that's basically like this:

```
public boolean send(String message) {

    if(out != null && !out.checkError()) {
        out.println(message);
        out.flush();
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    socket = new Socket(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT);

    out = new PrintWriter(
            new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

    while (mRun && (response = in.readLine()) != null && socket.isConnected()) {
        Message message = Message.obtain();

        if (message != null) {
            message.obj = response;
            mHandler.sendMessage(message);
        }
    }
}
```

So from the main `Thread` I send messages to the server using `TCPClient#send(String)`, but it will respond **asynchronously** using `mHandler.sendMessage(Message)`.

I was wondering, if in order to send messages synchronously (waiting for the server response before sending the next one) the architecture of my `TCPClient` should be different (I'm also new to `InputStream` and `OutputStream` so that's why I'm confused)  or if this client is good to go, and I have to implement the synchronization logic by myself (using **callbacks** and **flags**).

*PS: I'm asking this question because all socket tutorials have the same skeleton as the one I posted, but also, neither of them should **wait for the server response** in order to write again, as a requirement.*

Comment: where are you calling server thread.start() method ?

Comment: in `Activity#onStart()` callback, but I'm not narrowing it down specifically for Android, but I want to know about the java framework itself.